# How to select rows based categories in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categories

this is really trivial but can't believe I have wandered around for an hour and still can find the answer, so here you are:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({"cats":["a","b"], "vals":[1,2]})
    df.cats = df.cats.astype("category")
    df
```

[image: df looks like this]

My problem is how to select the row that its "cats" columns's category is "a". I know that `df.loc[df.cats == "a"]` will work but it's based on equality on element. Is there a way to select based on levels of category?

Comment: `Is there a way to select based on levels of category?`. This isn't clear to me, in particular `levels of category`. What input / output combination are you looking for?

Answer (score 7):

For those who are trying to filter rows based on a **numerical** categorical column:

```
df[df['col'] == pd.Interval(46, 53, closed='right')]
```

This would keep the rows where the `col` column has category `(46, 53]`.

This kind of categorical column is common when you discretize numerical columns using `pd.qcut()` method.

Answer (score 6):

This works:

```
df.cats[df.cats=='a']
```

**UPDATE**

The question was updated. New solution:

```
df[df.cats.cat.categories == ['a']]
```

Comment: Thanks. It works however it's not what I want. Is there a way to select rows based on the category not on the value.

Comment: I cant get the "update" to work, when trying to compare cat.categories to a list, I get an error of "Shapes must match".

Answer (score 4):

Using the [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin) function to create a boolean index is an approach that will extend to multiple categories, similar to R's `%in%` operator.

```
# will return desired subset
df[df.cats.isin(['a'])]

# can be extended to multiple categories
df[df.cats.isin(['a', 'b'])]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can query the categorical list using `df.cats.cat.categories` which prints output as

```
Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object')
```

For this case, to select a row with category of `'a'` which is `df.cats.cat.categories['0']`, you just use:

```py
df[df.cats == df.cats.cat.categories[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[df.cats.cat.categories == df.cats.cat.categories[0]]
```