# Fastest method of filtering a pandas data frame by category

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I have a very large data frame with 100 million rows and categorical columns. I would like to know if there is a faster way of selecting rows by category than using the `.isin()` method or `.join()` method mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945493/a-faster-alternative-to-pandas-isin-function).

Given that the data is already categorised, I thought that it should be very fast to select categories, but a few tests I ran had disappointing performances. The only other solution I found was from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33468566/how-to-select-rows-based-categories-in-pandas-dataframe), but the solution does not seem to work for pandas 0.20.2.

Here is an example data set.

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import string
df = pd.DataFrame({'categories': [random.choice(string.ascii_letters) 
                                  for _ in range(1000000)]*100,
                   'values': [random.choice([0,1]) 
                              for _ in range(1000000)]*100})
df['categories'] = df['categories'].astype('category')
```

Testing with `.isin()`:

```
%timeit df[df['categories'].isin(list(string.ascii_lowercase))]
44 s ± 894 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Using `.join()`:

```
%timeit df.set_index('categories').join(
    pd.Series(index=list(string.ascii_lowercase), name='temp'), 
    how='inner').rename_axis('categories').reset_index().drop('temp', 1)
24.7 s ± 1.69 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: just an FYI, the timings are *highly* depedent on the random seed here. you should fix one in your problem.

Comment: After running a few more tests, with each method using the same random seed and testing with my real data, I find the `map` method consistently faster, so I've marked that as the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a similar but different approach that directly compares the value rather than using `isin`.

Basic `map` / lambda comparison:

```
%timeit df[df['categories'].map(lambda x: x in string.ascii_lowercase)]
> 1 loop, best of 3: 12.3 s per loop
```

Using `isin`:

```
%timeit df[df['categories'].isin(list(string.ascii_lowercase))]
> 1 loop, best of 3: 55.1 s per loop
```

**Versions**: Py 3.5.1 / IPython 5.1.0 / Pandas 0.20.3

**Background**: I noticed in [one of the SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945493/a-faster-alternative-to-pandas-isin-function#comment36892872_23945493) you linked to that a commenter mentioned that `isin` needs to create a `set()` during the execution, so skipping that step and doing a basic list lookup seems to be the speedup here.

*Disclamer*: not the type of scale I deal with regularly, so there may be even faster options out there.

**Edit: Extra detail on request in comments from JohnGalt:**

```
df.shape
> (100000000, 2)
df.dtypes
> categories    category
 values           int64
 dtype: object
```

To create the sample data, I copy/pasted the sample DF from the initial question. Run on a MBP, early 2015 model.

Comment: Could you add `df.shape` and `df.dtypes` on which these timings were done?

Comment: @JohnGalt I see why you asked (very quick times), and I've just re-run and got different results. The only difference between the two runs is that I just upgraded my dev Pandas from 0.19 to current pip version of 0.20. I've updated the answer with new times, but will try again with the older python and see if the quicker results come back.

Comment: This does seem to perform better. Using the same example data from the question, I get the following performance:
`8.7 s ± 1.23 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`
I am just wondering if anything can be done with the `cat` methods of categories. For example, this is reasonably quick: `df['categories'].cat.set_categories(list(string.ascii_lowercase))`
but using `.loc` on the result is much slower.

Comment: @kayoz glad that I got you some small improvements. I'm not very familiar with Categories unfortunately so can't offer anything from experience there.

Comment: @JohnGalt just added now

Comment: @PhilSheard - Strange I don't see much difference in `0.21.x` actually. https://pastebin.com/7VswWZjx

Comment: @JohnGalt Yeah, that is strange. OP replied earlier in the thread and is seeing performance improvements from my answer, so I wonder if it's a hardware or some other subsystem between you and us?

Comment: @kayoz one extra tip I just thought of. In case you're repeating this process multiple times on the same data, you could create store the indexer into an object and re-use it, so that you're not doing the lookup more than once.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately my real data has a few hundred categories and the queries could access any combination of them. This solution is fast enough for my purposes, taking most queries down from ~1min to ~10s.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a run on 1/10 the sample. Groupby takes advantage of the categorical naturally. Currently the implementation of `df.loc[list_of_items]` for a Categorical is not very efficient, but *could* utilize this under the hood.

```
In [68]: %timeit -n 3 -r 1 df[df['categories'].isin(list(string.ascii_lowercase))]
3.67 s +- 0 ns per loop (mean +- std. dev. of 1 run, 3 loops each)

In [69]: s = set(list(string.ascii_lowercase))

In [70]: %timeit -n 3 -r 1 df.groupby('categories', as_index=False).filter(lambda x: x.name in s)
1.09 s +- 0 ns per loop (mean +- std. dev. of 1 run, 3 loops each)

In [71]: result2 = df.groupby('categories', as_index=False).filter(lambda x: x.name in s)

In [72]: result1 = df[df['categories'].isin(list(string.ascii_lowercase))]
result1.equals

In [73]: result1.equals(result2)
Out[73]: True
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jeff. I find Phil's solution with `map` to be faster than the groupby. I'm wondering if it's possible to use `df['categories'].cat.set_categories()` as a mask? As this operation seems to be very fast.